# For what values of a parameter is a given vector an eigenvector of a given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this multiple choice question from a previous exam:

For what values of $k$ is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\2\end{bmatrix}$ an eigenvector of $A = \begin{bmatrix}-1&2&k\\0&2&0\\2&-1&2\end{bmatrix}$?

The choices are $0$,$1$,$2$,$3$, and "None of the above".

I got the eigenvalues to be $\lambda = 2$ and $\lambda = 2k-1$. I substituted the second value in $\lambda I - A$ and then checked for all $k$, but none of them gave me $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\2\end{bmatrix}$ as an eigenvector. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this very easy: Recall that $v = (1, 0, 2)^\intercal$ is an eigenvector of your matrix $A$ iff $Av = \lambda v$ for a certain $\lambda$. We have

$$Av = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 & k \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & - 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 + 2k \\ 0 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} \stackrel{!}{=} \lambda \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

From $6 = 2 \lambda$ it follows that $\lambda = 4$. Plugging this into the first equation yields $-1 + 2k = 4$, this implies $k = 2$. Hence, $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ iff $k = 2$, the corresponding eigenvalue is in this case $\lambda = 3$.

Comment: I believe the third entry of $A \vec{v}$ should be 6.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, thanks! I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you, Jan!

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to think about this is that when you apply the matrix (call it $A$) to an eigenvector (call it $\vec{v}$), it yields a vector parallel to the original input eigenvector.

Under what conditions is a vector parallel to $\vec{v} = [1, 0, 2]^T$? If it is of the form $[t, 0, 2t]$, for any real number $t$. That is, its second entry must be zero, and its third entry must be twice its first entry.

We can see for your matrix, the second entry of is always zero, so our first condition is always satisfied. We can also see that the third entry is always $$6: hence, the first entry must be half of this, i.e. $3$.

The first entry evaluates to $-1 + 2k$, and we want this to be $3$. This yields $k = 2$, which is our answer.